# How to remove a string from another string in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a string containing sql statement as follows :

```
$sql = "SELECT nic_number, client_title, client_lastname FROM customer ORDER BY id_client LIMIT 0, 1";
```

I want to remove `LIMIT 0, 1` from it so as it becomes

```
SELECT nic_number, client_title, client_lastname FROM customer ORDER BY id_client
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Look up str_replace() though manipulating SQL queries as strings is usually best avoided anyway.

Comment: Why do you add LIMIT to the query if you don't want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = 'SELECT nic_number, client_title, client_lastname FROM customer ORDER BY id_client LIMIT 0, 1';
echo $sql = preg_replace('/LIMIT \d+, \d+/', '', $sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
echo str_replace("LIMIT 0, 1", "", $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content is always the same:

```
$sql = str_replace('LIMIT 0, 1', '', $sql);
```

Comment: if the limit is dynamic how kan 1 remove it LIMIT $X, $Y